# Update a table via a Form with Data from Inputs on the Form and from another table

Tags: forms

being new to coding I have run into a wall. I am attempting to update a table "Data_Tbl" from a Form "Form1" with inputs, and a value from a second table "Temp_Tbl" (Which contains predetermined temperature data) based on a Temperature keyed into a field on the Form. My "Temp_Tbl" has 2 fields "Temp" and "TDS" while the "Data_Tbl" has 3 fields to gather data from the form and "Temp_Tbl",  "Serial", "Temp" and "TDS".  I would like to populate the "TDS in the "Data_Tbl" from the "Temp_Tbl" based on the "Temp" keyed into the "Form1" and send it to the table "Data_Tbl" I have attempted to use the answers put forth in this site but to no avail. All I get are errors with the code. I am slightly familiar with VBA.  Any help would be appreciated. I have tried so many things, I don't know what to put as an example.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to mention on which database you need help in QUERY coding.

Comment: My apologies, It is in MS ACCESS 2016

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am attempting to Pull data from a control table into a form based on input into that form.  For example: Table one has a list of Temperatures and Control Numbers (Two fields in the table).  I want to pull the control number into the from based on the Temperature keyed into the form.